# I've imported some mysql data into the Django mysql db. How do I get Django models to work with my existing data?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I have an existing process building data daily.
I've copied tables from my main mysql to a test-mysql so I can work with the data and get it right.

I found an excellent post about building the correct model
`python manage.py inspectdb {tablename}`
which was 99% correct.

I have a table called `main` which I'd like to connect to the `main` model.

I've 50+ tables with titles like `1234` linked by a foreign key column called `G` to `G` in `main`.

I've just realised the way Django stores models is completely different.
It stores data in tables by `{appname}_{model}`

Have I gone about this backwards?

Should I have created the Django database first, and then added to it by its conventions?

I've already put a lot of work into this and it would be a lot to redo it. If its best, that's what I'll do.

Thanks,
T

Comment: Also is it a bad idea to have 50ish tables logging information? Should I put it one table, and just use selection/ filtering?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can avoid django manageing your database and link a model to an existing table:

```
Class YourModel(models.Model)
....
    Class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'table_name'
```